# Removing the space after the dollar sign in the output of PHP's money_format()

Tags: php, money-format

I use

```
money_format('%(#15.2n',$money)
```

It outputs something like

> $ 500.00

Is there a way to remove the space between the dollar sign and 500?

Comment: I think the above will print spaces, and where is the dollar sign come from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`money_format`<sup>[[docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)]</sup> may not even work on some platforms. It would be more reliable to use `number_format`<sup>[[docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)]</sup>:

```
echo '$' . number_format($money, 2); // '$12.44'
```

If you wanted it padded to a certain number of spaces, but with the dollar sign immediately before the number, you could also use `sprintf`<sup>[[docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)]</sup>:

```
echo printf("%15s", '$' . number_format($money, 2)); // '         $12.44'
```

Comment: And what about `-$12.44` ?

Answer (score 1):

use str_replace(" ", "", $string)

Comment: Some international formats (eg French) use spaces between the numbers instead of commas.  This would strip those spaces out.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the extra spaces is fairly simple. The code you're using is actually adding the padding. An example from the `money_format` documentation:

> // US national format, using () for negative numbers
>   // and 10 digits for left precision
>   setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
>   echo money_format('%(#10n', $number) . "\n";
>   `// ($        1,234.57)`

The `#15` in your example is the culprit. If you were to look at your reference inside of a `pre` tag you would actually see the number padded to 15 spaces.

```
 $                500.00
```

If you remove that...

```
money_format('%(.2n',$money)
```

You will get:

```
$500.00
```

You can also drop the `(` to not wrap the negative numbers in parentheses (the alternative is a `-` at the beginning). And if you actually still want that *and* the single space you reference in your expected result you can try:

```
money_format('%(#4.2n',$money)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
function my_money_format($number){
    return str_replace(" ", "",money_format('%+#10n', $number));
}
```

Comment: This is adding spaces, and then removing them again for no good reason... why pad at all?

Answer (score -2):

```
echo money_format('$%i', $number)
```